# Switch button to mute (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

What I am trying to do is have a settings page in my app and when a switch is clicked on (its original state is off) then it will mute the entire app.  So far what my code can do is mute only the current view and it works great until I either segue to my main view then that music is still playing that is associated with that and when I segue back to the settings page the mute switch is returned to its original off state and the music is playing once again.  I was wondering how to fix my code so that when turned on it mutes all noise. Here is my code thank you for reading and helping:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var songs = ""

var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(
        filename, withExtension: nil)
    if (url == nil) {
        println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return
    }

    var error: NSError? = nil
    backgroundMusicPlayer =
        AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
        println("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}

class settingsView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func switchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    playBackgroundMusic(songs)

    if mySwitch.on {
        backgroundMusicPlayer.pause()

    } else {

        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()

    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    songs = "settingsBackground.mp3"

    switchPressed(self)
    }

}
```

Comment: Store this switch value in NSUSerdefault and use that value of viewDidload or viewwillappear of each view controller. If it is on than increase volume and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this way:

**MainViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
    let status = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("playerStatus")
    if status == "Off"{
        if (backgroundMusicPlayer?.playing != nil){
            backgroundMusicPlayer?.stop()
        }
    }else{
        songs = "1.mp3"
        playBackgroundMusic(songs)
        }
    }
}
```

**settingsView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class settingsView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func switchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    if mySwitch.on {

        NSUserDefaults().setObject("on", forKey: "playerStatus")
        playBackgroundMusic(songs)

    } else {
        NSUserDefaults().setObject("Off", forKey: "playerStatus")
        backgroundMusicPlayer!.stop()

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let status = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("playerStatus")
    if status == "Off" {
        mySwitch.setOn(false, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is complete working project : https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Switch-with-AudioPlayer